# Open Locations Toggle in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows, geolocation, location, windows-phone-7.1

I like to know how to open location toogle in c#, for example for wifi i use this:

```
ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi;
connectionSettingsTask.Show();
```

I like a stuff like that but for location.

Answer (score 1):

Though, in **Windows Phone 8**, this can be done using

`Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-location:"))`

Answer (score 0):

There is no task to do this for you - each app that uses the location sensors is expected to have this setting in their own settings page.